# File transfer is freezing while copying

Tags: usb, freeze, copy

When I make any data transfer process (from computer to usb), after a couple of seconds file transfer process freezes. It be normal after a few minutes later but again freezes. If there would no problem, copy process will be fast. Unlikely my hard-disk works without any problem. Also Flash-disk hasn't got any problem. -I disgust to say that- USB works fine in other OSes.

Note: I am using 3.0 port and 3.0 USB-Driver. I have no 2.0 port on my laptop.

Comment: refr [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/397249/system-freezes-unresponsive-unusable-when-copying-large-file-to-usb)

Comment: It is not seen like a real solution, I feel myself like making up a value (not academic).  The problems is solving but a new problems occurs  like very slow transfer or a potential risk to lose integrity of data.

Comment: @Ravan, after a huge time span like one year, i want to thank you for your comment. It takes my one year to understand what is going on :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually it was not freezing or hanging, it just filled up the cache (that is why it was faster at some point and suddenly looks like freezing.)

To make sure the copying running. You can do strace to see if system call I/O is running.

Open terminal, then `ps -ef|grep <name_of_the_program>` and then `strace -p <prog_pid>`.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I will try it later, I have one more question that is maybe about cache, generally transfers begins with huge speed and drops slowly to lower numbers like from 90 mb/sec to 10 mb/sec. Is it a normal thing like can not underestimate the left time of the data transfer proccess?

Comment: The bottleneck is the speed on the disk write I/O. The actual speed is might vary based on the write speed of the disk.

To see it more clearly try to use `dd` utility.

Example:

`dd if=source_file of=target_location conv=fsync`. The `conv=fsync` flag sets to bypass the cache, hence synchronous I/O.

Answer (score -1):

This is a Disk Management issue. To stop a USB hard drive from freezing while copying data, you have to disable the default "Quick removal" and check the "Better performance" property in the Disk Management. This enables the "write caching", and in order to remove the drive without losing data, you must use the "Safely Remove Hardware" notification icon to disconnect the device safely.

Comment: As I know it is about "windows" solution. If I am wrong please lay solution way of the problem step by step to me. Because I can't find anything about these options.