# USB pendrive : the copy takes about 3 minutes but the unmount takes a very long time : 10 to 12 minutes

Tags: usb, ntfs, fat32, unmount

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10.

I formatted an USB pen-drive to NTFS to prepare a Windows7 USB Installer.

I set the bootable flag on this pen-drive and copied the files into it.

EDIT 1: The USB pen-drive is automatically mounted by udev.

`umount /dev/sdb1` takes from 10 upto 12 minutes to complete.

Here are the mount options :

```
$ mount | grep sdb
/dev/sdb1 on /media/mansfeld/Win7_USB_Installer type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
```

EDIT 2: The `cp` operation is not INSTANTANEOUS at all, it took 3 minutes to copy the files to the USB pen-drive.

EDIT 3: The `sync` operation (done right after the `cp`) took 12 minutes to complete ! But then the `umount` will be instantaneous.

For FAT32, (with sync also disabled during mount), I notice the same behaviour.

Any ideas why it takes so long to unmount NTFS USB pendrive ?

Comment: How do you unmount it (which command or GUI action)? Did you try with the following command line? `sudo umount /dev/sdb1`; Maybe there are some buffered data, that must be written to the drive before it can be unmounted. You can flush the buffers with `sync` ; After `sync` has returned to prompt, unmounting should be fast.

Comment: @sudodus The computer on which I ran this is at the university so I'll have to wait 'till monday to try and time the `sync` command.

Comment: I noticed your edit. This is according to my experience. Copying takes some time (at first it is fast (writing to RAM), but after a while, it must flush the buffer (when it is full or almost full according to some rule), and the copying will be slower). Yet, when the copy command finished (`cp`returns to prompt), there are still lots of data in the buffer. If you run `sync` right after the `cp` command, and wait until `sync` returns to prompt, the unmount should be fast. Please try that :-)

Comment: I think you know now :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are probably *suffering from <s>buffering</s> caching*. To speed up writing to USB sticks (and hard disks in general), Linux uses a filesystem cache:

When you (think you) write something to the stick then it is first written to the cache (in RAM) and the `cp` command (for instance) returns immediately pretending a really fast write operation. While you do other things, the contents of the cache is then written to the stick in background. You may notice that an LED on the stick still flashes showing write operations (depends on your stick) although nothing apparent happens.

When you issue `umount` soon after a write operation, then `umount` waits until all the filesystem's cache content is written to the stick in order to make sure no data gets lost.

With `sync` you can manually force emptying the cache and writing the data to the stick. However, this won't speed up the total elapsed time because then you will have to wait for the `sync` to complete (instead of waiting for `umount`). But the `umount` will then return instantaneously because the cache is already flushed.

In summary you have three choices after copying large or many files to the stick:

- `umount` and wait 10 minutes for it to complete
- `sync`, wait 10 minutes to complete, followed by `umount` (will return almost immediately)
- simply wait for 10 minutes (perhaps a bit more) and do nothing (or something unrelated to the stick) and *then* issue `umount`. Because the cache gets written in background automatically, `umount` will then return almost immediately as well.

Comment: Or mount the filesystem with -o sync flag enabled, that disables write caching.

Comment: Yes, @Pasi, that's another reasonable approach. Thank you for pointing that out. But then the "10 minutes" will kick in when you actually `cp` the files. It just depends on what behaviour you prefer. Waiting for `cp` or waiting for `umount`.

Comment: @PasiSuominen How can I have `udev` mount my USB pen-drive automatically with the `sync` option enabled ?

Comment: /etc/udev/rules.d/ is your answer. In udev rule you can specify mount parameters.

Comment: @PasiSuominen On ubuntu server, this dir is empty, what else can I do ?

Comment: You can specify your device on /etc/fstab

Answer (score 5):

When you copy files to your pendrive, they are not written on it directly. Filesystem synchronization is happening on unmount command, the actual data is written while you wait your unmount. If you execute `sync` before `umount`, the `umount` is instant.

Comment: The computer on which I ran this is at the university so I'll have to wait 'till monday to try and time the `sync` command.

Comment: I'll have to wait till monday for the sync to finish!

Answer (score 1):

As a side note, if you want to copy something to USB drive and then check `sync`'ing, you could use my small tool, `usbcp`:

[`https://github.com/satk0/usbdrivetools`](https://github.com/satk0/usbdrivetools)

Example:

```bash
usbcp file mounted/pendrive
```

Yea, I know it's an advert but I would be more than happy if even one single person besides me could find this tool useful !