# Ubuntu 19.10 cursor freezes

Tags: 19.10, cursor

On Ubuntu 19.10, my cursor freezes after a long period of time not using the system. The keyboard works fine then, though.

My laptop is a 2011 MacBookPro, where I'm only using the Intel videocard, as the Radeon card is defective. I boot 19.10 normally, and 19.10 runs very stable on this machine, unlike Elementary OS even when bypassing the Radeon video card.

Comment: In the terminal write modprobe -r psmouse

Comment: Have you added any GNOME Shell extensions? Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: Is it just the mouse, or is the whole OS freezing? If the latter, see [here][1] and report back as to whether disabling secure boot fixes things.

  [1]: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182753/lots-of-soft-locks-after-upgrade-to-linux-image-5-3-0-19-generic

Comment: @heynnema, Thanks for reaching out. I tried Kubuntu 19.10, Mate 19.10. All same issues. Seems like a kernel issue. Found this https://askubuntu.com/a/1183594

Comment: You didn't answer my question about GNOME Shell extensions. Also, edit your question and show me `free -h`, and screenshot(s) of the `Disks` app SMART Data.

Comment: the same thing here. It's not just the cursor, it's the whole system, keyboard doesn't respond either. It happens at random.

Comment: @heynnema I have not installed any gnome extensions. I am using stock Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: If you want the help, I'll be glad to, but you have to answer my questions. Read my prior comments.

Comment: @heynnema ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions ls: cannot access '/home/avi/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions': No such file or directory

Comment: @MikeLawrence Secure boot is already disabled.

Comment: Ok so, I noticed that whenever I am copying pasting files, or opening programs, games, the cursor freezes randomly. I do not encounter this doing similar operations on Ubuntu 18.04.3

Comment: I **still** need to see `free -h` and screenshot(s) of the `Disks` app SMART Data. (*asked 7 days ago*).

Comment: @heynnema. You have been wonderful in trying to help. I removed 19.10 and installed 18.04.3 as the desktop became unusable. Hopefully the next LTS will work as a charm as does 18.04. :).

Comment: Try to temporarily disable swap with `sudo swapoff -a` and see if you still get laggy performance. I have a hypothesis that this may be related to swapping.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184366/lagging-after-update-to-19-10-from-19-04/1184571#1184571

Comment: `sudo swapoff -a` seems to work but need a more permanent solution