# Lots of soft-locks after upgrade to linux-image-5.3.0-19-generic

Tags: upgrade, kernel, 19.10

Been using 19.10 for a couple weeks and running `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` daily with no issues until today when it seems to have updated the kernel (that's what `linux-image``linux-headers`\etc are about, right?) and now I'm getting frequent soft-locks. Any ideas on how I can troubleshoot this? Here's a screenshot from one of the bug reports:
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#2 stuck for 23s! \[plymouthd:305\]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/875173/nmi-watchdog-bug-soft-lockup-cpu2-stuck-for-23s-plymouthd305)

Answer (score 0):

I booted with a live-usb, didn't experience the soft-locks at all and was about to do a full re-install when the installer notified me that I had secure boot enabled. I have a memory of disabling that ages ago, so on a hunch I quit the installer and exited the live-usb, entered my bios settings and disabled secure boot, then rebooted into my previously soft-locking ubuntu install and have yet to encounter a soft-lock after an hour of use. So I think it's fixed? Anyone have any ideas on how secure boot would have been re-enabled like that and how that could out of nowhere start causing soft-locks?

Comment: Not sure if it's related, but I also just noticed that my `/usr/local/bin` folder is gone.