# 19.10 hangs for a few seconds every minute or so

Tags: performance, 19.10

System just hangs (freezes) for a few seconds. Mouse cursor does not move and display does not update, but keyboard buffer fills. Then things are fine again for a minute.

`top` does not show anything useful that I can see. There are some irqs showing but I do not have enough experience to know if they are excessive.

Lenovo L340 Gaming laptop

Happens regardless of USB devices plugged in and regardless of external monitor.

Happens with Nvidia non-free drivers and without.

System is fine for the first 10 minutes or so and then the hangs become more frequent until the machine is so useless that I have to reboot.

```
ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 jennifer jennifer 4096 Oct 22 09:06 .
drwx------ 3 jennifer jennifer 4096 Oct 22 09:38 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 jennifer jennifer 4096 Oct 22 09:06 weatherintheclock@JasonLG1979.github.io
```

Comment: Was it the same situation with 19.04 or 18.04?

Comment: I [encountered the same thing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182753/lots-of-soft-locks-after-upgrade-to-linux-image-5-3-0-19-generic) out of nowhere yesterday and today think I solved it by [re-disabling secure boot in my bios](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182753/lots-of-soft-locks-after-upgrade-to-linux-image-5-3-0-19-generic/1182958#1182958).

Comment: @darksky, yes same in 19.04.  Did not try 18.04

Comment: Mike Lawrence, I have secure boot disabled.  Will try enabling it then re-disabling.

Comment: Seems to be solved.  I initially had secure boot disabled when I had problems.  Mike Lawrence suggested re-disabling secure boot so I did that.  I enabled secure boot and booted into Ubuntu, then disabled secure boot and now no hanging.  Oddly with secure boot enabled, the NVidia drivers do not see the HDMI port so no external monitor.    What a strange thing.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem after upgrading to Ubuntu 19.10.

I checked out my `/var/log/syslog` for clues and I noticed there were a lot of lines regarding `iwlwifi` even if I was not connected to any Wifi networks.

I disabled my wifi and I had no hangs after that.