# 19.10 slow or non responsive keyboard, not able to login after screen saver

Tags: keyboard

Ubuntu 19.10 slow or non responsive keyboard. Browser locks up Firefox and Chrome. I'm not able to login after screen saver.

Specs:

- Memory 15.6 GB
- Intel Core i5-4690kx4
- GeForce GTX970/PCie/SSE2
- OS 64-bit
- 2-500 GB SSD's

Comment: What does `uname -r` report? There have been many reports of 19.10 buggy performance due to new kernel: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184366/lagging-after-update-to-19-10-from-19-04/1184571#1184571

Comment: 5.3.0-23-generic

Comment: That's the same kernel version others had problems with in the link.

Comment: I had similar issues with 19.04. Only keyboard, Just put up with it. Update end of November correct? Do not want to back rev kernals

Comment: I install new kernels all the time. Have never really run the one Ubuntu supplies. I stick on the same five year LTS kernel chain though. So I'm on 4.14.153 now. As long as everyone is happy with how they manage their Linux Kernels it doesn't really matter. Personally I don't put up with bugs though, if I see one I switch kernel versions right away.