# freeze with audio loop, must reboot

Tags: sound, internet, freeze

I’d been having freezes and crashes with Ubuntu 18.04, especially while playing audio/video from the internet, so I upgraded it to 20.04, and then to 22.04, hoping this would have been sorted out. It hasn’t. The behaviour is this: everything stalls, the screen freezes mouse or keyboard do not respond, and curiously, the audio that was playing (it might be someone I’m talking to on Skype, or from a YouTube video) keeps repeating a 1-second loop like a broken record (“like a broken rec− like a broken rec− like a broken rec− like broken a rec− like broken a rec−” &c). Any ideas what causes this and how to fix it?
My kernel is: 5.15.0-53-lowlatency

Comment: Keyboard does not respond?  Does that include SysRq commands direct from keyboard to linux kernel? (*which bypass any locked screen/GUI/user-application*).  Have you tried the normal kernel? as it can provide better *stability* and performance for some hardware which most software (*when contrasted with low-latency which is for special case usage*).  If your issue is *configuration* related, it would be expected to survive *release-upgrades* (ie. upgrades from 18.04 to 20.04 etc won't make any difference).

Comment: I remember these freezes with the audio stuck in a loop all too well. I think for me it was mainly on Xubuntu, around 2012-13. From 2016, I hardly experience them any more, on vanilla Ubuntu. There is one specific thing I did: I have bought a laptop with ECC (Error Code Correction) memory, and corresponding processor, for this very reason. I can't tell whether it's this that helped, or something else. Apart from that, we have a community member who regularly helped ([example](https://askubuntu.com/a/1189762/1157519)) solving freezes through tweaking something with the "swap" settings.

Comment: Additionally, more info on SysRq, and the graceful reboot attempt: https://askubuntu.com/a/36717/1157519

Comment: There is somehow this problem I faced too on 22.04, the system settings lag after switching to another input. Workaround I found is after turning on the computer I try to modify input to my desired mic directly and not touching it later on after opening application that required one.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I’ll try what’s been suggested.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My screen freezes when I'm multitasking and videos loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1364590/my-screen-freezes-when-im-multitasking-and-videos-loop)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to graphics driver compatibility. I had a very similar problem and was struggling for few months but finally adding a `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` did the magic. I had an Intel integrated graphics so Ubuntu driver manager showed "No drivers needed".

```
Section "Device"
 Identifier "Intel Graphics"
 Driver "intel"
EndSection
```

This would make sure your graphics drivers are loaded correctly.

The Arch Linux [Intel graphics wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/intel_graphics) is also very helpful.

***Note:***  *You could have other graphics drivers so please make changes accordingly. This would also help people looking for solution and struggling for months as it is very common problem with Intel integrated graphics drivers and Ubuntu.*

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you still have this issue or not. But I fixed mine by turning off the power management of wifi.
first, try to find the power management is on or off.

```
iwconfig
```

if **Power Management: on**

open your network manager power management option by

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

you'll find

**wifi.powersave = 3**

*change this 3 to 2.*

now reboot your PC
then check again

```
iwconfig
```

**Power Management:off**

this should solve the problem.